# About reducing question reputation

Tags: support, down-votes

I posted a question and somebody downvoted it. That is really bad. First you need to ask the poster what they meant by it OR suggest to improve the question.

Who has privilege to downvote? Without thinking about validity,people just downvote it.

Comment: I'm sorry, is there a question here? Or are you just ranting?

Comment: What exactly is the question? If you're talking about people downvoting, it's because posts like this. You need to clarify what you're question is, or people will be confused.

Comment: I believe there is a question in my 5 sentences. 4th sentence is the question. I just explained first what happened on site.

Comment: @user583726: Yes, I see, but when you say "Who does downvote", do you mean "What kind of person would downvote?" or "Who is downvoting?"

Comment: now this kind of conversation can lead to make corrections. I meant who has privilege to downvote ?

Comment: @user583726: Those with a reputation score of 125+ are allowed to downvote.

Comment: Don't radically alter your question in this manner, user. If you'd rather your question not exist, flag it for deletion.

Comment: @user583726: I'm agreeing with Michael Petrotta here, but you might also want to fix you're post's title as well.

Comment: @user583726 - As far as downvotes on meta goes, don't let this bug you. On meta, they just mean people disagree with you or that this is information you could have found by searching. As Michael says in his answer, don't take this the wrong way. This community *works* precisely because people work so hard to keep it clean, and we're hoping that you'll become one of those people as well. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably, you're referring to [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130888/facebook-referral-dialog-not-working), posted just over two hours ago.

Minitech replied with a comment, explaining why he considered it a poor question. He's right. I'd walk though your question in more detail, explaining what's gone wrong with it, but were I you, I'd just read Minitech's comment more carefully.

Downvotes are not, as you say, "really bad". They are a means for users to signal that they consider your question poor. This indicates to future visitors that they shouldn't visit your question - it probably won't help them. It you gather enough downvotes on your questions and answers, you'll lose the privilege to post here - we do that to lower the noise floor, and that's been enormously beneficial.

It is easy to take downvotes personally. Many have. Don't be one of them - [learn from this](http://lifehacker.com/5863490/how-to-learn-from-your-mistakes). Improve. That's what the human condition is really about, after all.

To answer the question you pose in your edit, users who've gained the [Vote down questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) privilege are able to downvote questions and answers. The amount of reputation required for that varies by site, and is currently 125 on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am newbie and I might make mistake. doing downvote simultaneously user will be kicked out of site. How that is beneficial ?

Comment: @user, by improving the overall quality level on this site. You have some time to improve your works - you won't be "kicked out" immediately. This is only your first downvoted post - learn from it.